# How to use docker and PySpark

Tags: docker, pyspark

I'm starting to use PySpark. I'm wondering how to use containerization with PySpark.
I would like to isolate my python application and dependencies in a container.
Can I place my python application within a container and give the image directly to a spark cluster? Will it be able to make his work and distribute the image to the workers and then distribute the work to the multiple "containers"?

Answer (score 0):

For developing Spark applications in a container you could use:

- `jupyter/pyspark-notebook`. There's also SparkUI which you can access on port `4040`. More information here: [Jupyter Apache Spark](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/specifics.html#apache-spark)
- Or AWS Glue docker image: `amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_1.0.0_image_01`. More information on how to set it up: [Developing AWS Glue ETL jobs locally using a container](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/developing-aws-glue-etl-jobs-locally-using-a-container/)

When your application is ready, you can just submit it to the cluster. I'm not sure why docker is needed at that point.

Comment: Thanks Vlad but I'm already using spark cluster running in docker. I already submitted code to it.
What I would like to know is "Can I isolate my code and dependencies into a container?"
I would like to be sure to share with my coworkers the exact same application that will run in production cluster